# How to merge dataframes and simultanously recode NA's based on values of other rows?

Tags: r

I want to do something which should be relatively easy but I'm finding it impossible. (Relatively new into R).

I have these two datasets:

```
df1 <- data.frame("Basket" = c("W1", "W1"),          
             "Fruits" = c("apple", "banana"),
             "Color" = c("green", "yellow"),
             "Spanishfruit" = c("manzana", "platano"),
             "Spanishcolor" = c("verde", "amarillo"))

df <- data.frame("Basket" = c("W2", "W2", "W2"),          
              "Fruits" = c("apple", "banana", "grape"),
              "Color" = c("green", "yellow", "purple"),
              "Spanishfruit" = c(NA, NA, NA),
              "Spanishcolor" = c(NA, NA, NA))
```

First, I want to merge them (I'm using bind_rows for that), which is working. However, I also want to recode NA's in the second dataframe so that if the variables fruit and colour are equal between the datasets (and the variable basket is not), the variables "Spanishfruit" and "Spanishcolour" (simply its translations to Spanish) are equal. I.e., I only managed to arrive to this:

```
df3 <- data.frame("Round" = c("W1", "W1","W2", "W2", "W2" ),          
              "Fruits" = c("apple", "banana", "apple", "banana", "grape"),
              "Color" = c("green", "yellow", "green", "yellow", "purple"),
              "Spanishfruit" = c("manzana", "platano", NA, NA, NA),
              "Spanishcolor" = c("verde", "amarillo", NA, NA, NA))
```

But what I want is this.

```
df4 <- data.frame("Round" = c("W1", "W1","W2", "W2", "W2" ),          
              "Fruits" = c("apple", "banana", "apple", "banana", "grape"),
              "Color" = c("green", "yellow", "green", "yellow", "purple"),
              "Spanishfruit" = c("manzana", "platano", "manzana", "platano", NA),
              "Spanishcolor" = c("verde", "amarillo", "verde", "amarillo", NA))
```

I tried several things so far, mostly combining mutate and case_when. I'm thinking the solution might by in merging and establishing the right keys when merging them? I'm really lost and cannot find a solution to this problem anywhere. What I want is that if the values in the columns "fruits" and "color" are equal across one row from df1 and another row from df2, when I merge them, values in "Spanishfruit" and "Spanishcolor" in the rwo from df2 is equal to value in row from df1, while variable basket is still different. Or, put differently: if the values for two variables across rows are equal, I want that the values for two variables to be equal as well, while keeping another variable different.

I'll be really thankful if someone knows how to solve this. It'd be extra helpful to find a tidyverse-based solution, but everything would help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is this the output you are looking for?

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame("Basket" = c("W1", "W1"),          
               "Fruits" = c("apple", "banana"),
               "Color" = c("green", "yellow"),
               "Spanishfruit" = c("manzana", "platano"),
               "Spanishcolor" = c("verde", "amarillo"))

df <- data.frame("Basket" = c("W2", "W2", "W2"),          
              "Fruits" = c("apple", "banana", "grape"),
              "Color" = c("green", "yellow", "purple"),
              "Spanishfruit" = c(NA, NA, NA),
              "Spanishcolor" = c(NA, NA, NA))

df3 <-rbind(df, df1)

df3 %>% group_by(Fruits) %>%
        mutate(Spanishfruit = zoo::na.locf(Spanishfruit, na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = TRUE),
               Spanishcolor = zoo::na.locf(Spanishcolor, na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = TRUE)) %>%
       arrange(Basket, desc())
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#> # Groups:   Fruits [3]
#>   Basket Fruits Color  Spanishfruit Spanishcolor
#>   <fct>  <fct>  <fct>  <chr>        <chr>       
#> 1 W2     apple  green  manzana      verde       
#> 2 W2     banana yellow platano      amarillo    
#> 3 W2     grape  purple <NA>         <NA>        
#> 4 W1     apple  green  manzana      verde       
#> 5 W1     banana yellow platano      amarillo
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: You might want to use na.locf0 instead in which case you don't need the na.rm argument.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Your solution looked very promising. Unfortunately, for some reason I still didn't get, it is not working on my real dataset. The problem seems to be that when I have to group_by based on several variables (which are string characters) and, for some reason, R won't recognise the string characters to be equal and hence won't do thge appropriate grouping. So unfortunate, but your solution will still be extremely useful for the future. Thanks!

Comment: That’s too bad. If you can share more of the data where this approach fails I’m sure I or somebody else here can help.